Why Email Logs are empty when the email has been queued from Apex?
There is an Apex method that sends a SingleEmailMessage.
List<Messaging.SendEmailResult> results = Messaging.sendEmail(new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>{message});

It has been working as intended for a year until a month ago the emails suddenly stopped coming. No changes have been made to the code from our side.
SendEmailResult shows the email has been sent successfully.
Debug Logs shows the email has been successfully queued:
EMAIL_QUEUE|[131]|subject: '..', senderDisplayName: '..', bccSender: false, saveAsActivity: true, 
useSignature: true, toAddresses: '..', whatId: '..', plainTextBody: '..', htmlBody: '..'.

When in such circumstances the email is not sent in the end, I expect Email Logs to contain some information about why it happened. But in my case, there is absolutely no sign of the email at all.
Email Logs request:
All emails between 7/15/2024, 4:17 PM - 7/22/2024, 4:17 PM with search filter Email_Direction IN ("Outbound", "Inbound").
I had a feeling Email Logs are always there in such cases. Was my assumption wrong? Or have I missed something?
Is there other place where I can look for useful information, given the email has been queued, but not sent?
Thanks for all the help.
Other details:

In Sandbox the method works fine.
The method is called by a Community User. I've checked the profile and have found no lack of permissions;
In the Activity tab of the Case, there is a record that indicates a successful sending. The link navigates to a task, which says the email has been sent successfully;
I've tried different domains as sender and recipient, including one that uses Email Relay. No effect.


EMAIL_QUEUE and SendEmailResult with isSuccess() = true represent the same information - that a request to send was queued.  When the queued request is processed by the platform, it can then be dropped for a number of reasons. Since this works in the sandbox, violation of a daily send limit is the likeliest possibility. Calling Messaging.reserveSingleEmailCapacity(...) prior to Messaging.sendEmail is one way to ensure you don't hit your daily limit.

@identigral I ensured this is not the case while reproducing the issue.

If so, you should edit your question and add this information.

@identigral no offense, but
a) it's obvious from details of the question that daily limit is not the cause.
b) we have already discussed that assumption in the comments just below the question, which is enough in my opinion.
Sometimes I get a feeling people leave comments here for show.
